# Why doesn't python setup.py build/install work?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to install a python package here, called pips. https://github.com/jbloom/pips-1.0#using-pips

I follow all the directions, using:

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

as root. I then try to load pips in python (ipython), using:

```
import pips
```

However, it doesn't recognize this program. My python installation is 2.7, which should be compatible with the package. Am I doing something wrong?

Edit: The output I get to the setup.py install is:

```
[root@tawfik pips-1.0-master]# python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
running build_scripts
running install_lib
running install_scripts
changing mode of /usr/bin/pips_consensus.py to 775
changing mode of /usr/bin/pips_run_cupsat.py to 775
changing mode of /usr/bin/pips_build_tree_and_alignment.py to 775
changing mode of /usr/bin/pips_analysis.py to 775
changing mode of /usr/bin/pips_run_foldx.py to 775
changing mode of /usr/bin/pips_correlate_selected_mutations.py to 775
changing mode of /usr/bin/pips_analyze_selected_mutations.py to 775
running install_egg_info
Removing /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pips-1.0-py2.6.egg-info
Writing /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pips-1.0-py2.6.egg-info
```

Comment: My guess is `pip` installs to a different interpreter. This is a common issue. What is the output of `which pip` and `which python` (assuming you are on Unix)?

Comment: It says there is no pips when I search with 'which pips'. This is strange because it doesn't give me an error when I run the installation code.

Comment: @mbatchkarov: he is installing the `pips` package, not using the `python-pip` tool. @Devinity: can you give the output of your run of `python setup.py install`?

Comment: [root@tawfik pips-1.0-master]# python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
running build_scripts
running install_lib
running install_scripts
changing mode of /usr/bin/pips_consensus.py to 775
changing mode of /usr/bin/pips_run_cupsat.py to 775
changing mode of /usr/bin/pips_build_tree_and_alignment.py to 775
changing mode of /usr/bin/pips_analysis.py to 775
changing mode of /usr/bin/pips_run_foldx.py to 775
changing mode of /usr/bin/pips_correlate_selected_mutations.py to 775

Comment: changing mode of /usr/bin/pips_analyze_selected_mutations.py to 775
running install_egg_info
Removing /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pips-1.0-py2.6.egg-info
Writing /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pips-1.0-py2.6.egg-info

Comment: **I have no idea what any of this means.**

Comment: Add it by editing the question, not in the comments :). (You seem to be installing to python2.6 tough).

Comment: How do I change this, I noticed that before but I don't even have python 2.6...

Comment: Can you please add the output you gave to the question first? It's very difficult to read in the comments (people won't want to read it, and thus cannot help you).

Comment: how do you start your `python` interpreter? could it be that `ipython` has installed its own version of python and your OS came with 2.6 preinstalled (which it then runs when you use the `python` command to install pips)?

Comment: Yes, actually this is probably why. I'm on centos which comes with 2.6. How do I install pips to 2.7? (this is what ipython calls, can I install from within ipython?)

Comment: `ipython setup.py build` then `ipython setup.py install` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is, as noted in the discussion, that there are two versions of my python installed in my system. One the OS (centos 6.4) uses, the other is used by my ipython distribution. I needed to install using ipython, rather than the OS python.